# How can we access network through an application created for snap?

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, package-managers, snapcraft

I have created a simple executable which when run directly on Ubuntu, opens an url using firefox but when installed as a part of snap package, it fails with "firefox : not found" error although i have provided a network plug.

Answer (score 1):

Use xdg-open in your application to launch the url using the default web browser. On the host running the snap, they need to have `snapd-xdg-open` (so `apt install snapd-xdg-open`) installed. This will be fixed in a future snapd release.

Comment: I have tried installing snapd-xdg-open and then using the xdg-open command in my source file. It works fine as a stand alone executable but when i install it as a part of snap package, it doesn't work. I do not get any error either. In my snapcraft.yaml, I have provided the 'network' plug and set confinement to strict and grade stable. Is there something I am missing here? ( like do I need to add some header in the source file for the snapd-xdg-open?)

Comment: Having the same issue as @Abhishek